# Get Response and Handle Errors for Google Cloud StorageClient $bucket->upload

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have just created my first app that talks to Google.

It currently successfully uploads to a bucket, everything is working nicely.

One thing I can't seem to find is good documentation on how to perform error handling when using `StorageClient`.

A simplified version of the code I'm using is below:

```
function test_bucket_upload($file_source)
{   

    $bucketName="my-bucket"; 
    $objectName = "my-object";
    $uploadName = "some-dir/{$objectName}";

    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $file = fopen($file_source, 'r');
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $uploadName
    ]);
}
```

I can see in [The Code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/master/src/Storage/Bucket.php) for the upload function, that a new StorageClient object is returned but every time I try and access the response variables, I get a `500 internal server error`.

I would like to be able to do a check on whether the upload succeeded.

I've had a pretty good look on the web but again, I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to perform this check.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled in PHP? If you're getting a 500 error you should also see some information from PHP about what's gone wrong. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm having to develop this in a bit of a weird environment. I'm making a wordpress plugin on an install running on a google VM instance. I was struggling to get the `gcloud` utilities running within my local container so I'm having to develop it in production =0[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP cloud storage library throws [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) on error. Specifically it will through a subclass of [GoogleException](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.56.0/core/exception/googleexception), e.g. BadRequestException, ConflictException, NotFoundException or ServerException.

To handle errors, use `try { ... } catch (GoogleException $e) { ... }` (or one of the sub-classes if you want to specifically handle 404 differently, for example).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I knew there would be something simple like this I'm just against a bit of a deadline and couldn't see any obvious way to do it. Now that I've gone back to look for this, I can see they have included a `try { ... } catch { ... }` block in the example of using the `getResumableUploader($data, array $options = [])` function.